# What is wrong with my UITableView cellForRowAtIndex for Single Selection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Below is code for `UITableView`, But when i scroll its behaves weirdly (too annoying)... This problem is due to reuseIdentifier.... but dont know how to solve..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSInteger imgTag = 1;
    NSInteger lblTag = 2;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, 52, 52)];
//        Image:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.glassType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        imgView.tag = imgTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
        [imgView release];

        UILabel *lblName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, cell.frame.size.height/4, 200, 21)];
//        lblName.text = [self.glassName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        lblName.tag = lblTag;
        [cell addSubview:lblName];
        [lblName release];
    }

    NSInteger imgIndex = 2;
    NSInteger lblIndex = 3;

    ((UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:imgTag]).image = [[self.glassType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:imgIndex];
    ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:lblTag]).text = [[self.glassName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:lblIndex];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

How to make Cell for row at index so that it remains constant even when scrolled??? Also how to make single selection in `UITableView`??

Comment: you should use tags 100 and up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that you should not add subviews to your table cells outside of the "if (cell == nil) { ..." clause or they get added over and over again to the same cell when it gets re-used.

See my answer to this question for a more detailed explanation, including code for how to fix it:

[cellForRowAtIndexPath memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859735/cellforrowatindexpath-memory-management/8859833#8859833)

You also cannot store state in table cells because as soon as they scroll offscreen they are recycled and re-appear at a different index in your table. You need to set up an array of model objects to store state for your table cells (such as what their accessory type should be). A more detailed explanation can be found in my answer to this question:

[Looping through UITableViewCells of a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859638/looping-through-uitableviewcells-of-a-uitableview/8859693#8859693)

If you fix how you are adding subviews to the cells, and store your "ticked" state in an array of model objects as well as setting the cell.accessoryType (so that it can be restored when the cell is dequeued), then your approach to row selection is otherwise correct.

So put this in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, just before the `return cell;`:

```
MyModelObject *object = [self.arrayOfModelObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
BOOL isChecked = object.checked;
cell.accessoryType = isChecked? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark: UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

And in your `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, get rid of the current logic and replace it with:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.arrayOfModelObjects count]; i++)
    {
        MyModelObject *object = [self.arrayOfModelObjects objectAtIndex:i];
        object.checked = (i == indexPath.row); // only check the one we just tapped
    }

    //refresh table to update the accessory views for all rows
    [tableView1 reloadData];
}
```

Obviously replace the `arrayOfModelObjects` with your own model implementation. You could just use an array of NSNumber objects containing bools if you don't want to create a custom class for this purpose.

Comment: Please see my updated code.. it still behaves wierdly... My images goes randomly on scrolling. I have keep my code inside **if** block and still problem persist...

Comment: @DShah Did you read Nick's answer at his first link? Read his answer, and follow the model in that code. **hint** Look at the use of tags and where the `if(cell == nil){}` ends.

Comment: It's a bit confusing updating your question to code that now works without including a comment to explain that you've done so. Also, if I've solved your problem, can you accept the answer - I get more points that way :-)

Comment: Hey, Now I am having same problem with cell.accessoryType... when i scroll i have some cells selected. What i want is only one cell should be selected at time.. For above code, i can handle objects but how to do for accessoryType??

Comment: Store the checked state for each row in an array. An array of NSNumber objects containing bools will do if you're not already using an array of custom objects as your dataSource. When you tap a cell, set the correct bool in the array to true and clear all the others to false. Then reload the table using [tableView reloadData]. Set the accessoryType in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method based on the bool in the array.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a code sample for the principle in my previous comment.

Comment: Can anyone help me to store the ticked state in array of objects

Answer (score 1):

**The recycling queue is like a pool where previously created Cells are stored** before to reuse them. For example when you scrolls up, at the moment the cell disappears above, it is stored in the queue and becomes available for the cell that will appear at the bottom. Ok ?

Actually **the number of cells really created is exactly the max simultaneous cell you can display in your table** (in most cases from 3 to 8). In other words your `if (cell == nil)` code is executed (more or less from 3 to 8 times) at the first reloadData to create the pool of cells your table needs.

**Then all you make on a cell is kept as it and appears again when you dequeue it**. It's now easy to understand that, in your code, you have to make all strictly row-dependant settings outside the if (cell == nil) block. The same way, do not add subViews outside the `if (cell == nil)` block, you can imagine the thousands of subview you will add each time you reset a dequeued cell !

**Tip:** if you need some custom cleanup before reusing a cell (like to set an image to blank), you can create a custom `UITableviewCell` class and implements the `prepareForReuse` method.

Is it clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Always reload your tableView in viewWillAppear method instead of viewDidLoad.

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

  [self.tableView reloadData];

  }

This avoids most of all unexpected and annoying problems. :)